# Assigning physical memory to a process in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, kernel

Is there a way to assign specific physical memory to a process in Linux?  I am contemplating a system where some regions of memory are faster than others.  I'd like to have a particular process use the faster memory (eg. for video processing).  Are there Linux features or sub-systems that let me do this?  Maybe NUMA or cgroups?

What would the mechanism be to reserve a region of physical memory, and assign it for the use of a particular process or group of processes.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that the system is non-x86, and there is no BIOS support for reporting the different memory as NUMA nodes.  Rather, there are multiple RAM slots, with some which can be parallelized, resulting in some memory allowing 64-bit (interleaved) access and some 32-bit access on the bus.  This is invisible to Linux, but if a process knows it is accessing the 64-bit interleaved memory, it can utilize the memory interleaving for higher memory bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify per process NUMA node for memory allocations with `numactl`:

```
numactl --membind=2,4 mycommand
```

You can also have the process choose nodes with `mbind`, and you can use `numactl` on tmpfs files if they're being mmapped.

Comment: Thanks! This answers the part of the question about assigning a node to a process.  How does one specify different physical memory regions be assigned to different NUMA nodes?

Comment: If the hardware has non-uniform memory access, it should already be providing the kernel with this information. If it doesn't, you should look at whether there's a BIOS update or something that will make it aware of its own access topology. Alternatively, there's [NUMA emulation](http://linux-hacks.blogspot.com/2009/07/fake-numa-nodes-in-linux.html) support that you may be able to trick into doing that

Comment: OK - there is no BIOS reporting NUMA nodes.  It looks like the NUMA fake node emulation is exactly what I need.  Thanks!